# Helper function and abstraction in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstraction

Considering 16.3.2 Helper Functions  of c++ programming language of Bjarne Stroustrup  suppose we have an interface

```
namespace IO
{
   class IImge
   {
   public:
       virtual double getThreshold() = 0;
       ...
   }
}
```

we have a concrete class

```
namespace IO
{
    class Image :public IImge
    {
    public:
        double getThreshold() override {return 20.0}
    }
}
```

and assume we want to add a helper function like this

```
double getNormalizedThreshold(IImage* image) {return image->getThreshold() / 100;}
```

where to put function declaration? In IImage or Image?

Comment: `getNormalizedThreshold` should be static?

Comment: do you mean in which file or in which namespace? Not in a class, because this should be a free function

Comment: Shouldn't it be inside `Image` since it has `getThreshold`. The parent `IImge` does not implement the function `getThreshold`...?

Comment: You should probably name your namespace, unless you actually want an anonymous namespace with no linkage.

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean. For example are you questioning whether to make it a member function of one of those classes (hint:don't), or what file to place it in as a free function (hint: opinion-based). Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your helper function has no need to know of `Image`, the logical place to put it is with `IImage`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is a bit opinion based. My personal feeling on this is that helper functions should be declared in a namespace, not inside any of the classes, and should only use the public API of such classes. They should be grouped by purpose and intended use.